# echo element from end of list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails project, I have a list that I want echo all element of this list from end to begin. I use below code:

`views/tests/_form.html.erb`

```
  <% list = Task.all %>
  <% list.each do |element| %>
     <%= element.id %><br/>
  <% end %>
```

By this code, I can echo all elemetns from begin of the list, but I want echo element from end of list to begin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean iterate backwards over the list?

```
  <% list = Task.all %>
  <% list.reverse_each do |element| %>
     <%= element.id %><br/>
  <% end %>
```

See [Array#reverse_each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each)

Comment: Iterate backwards, I use `.reverse_each`, but echo all element from begin of the list again.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you are asking.  `reverse_each` will let you iterate backwards through `list` without changing how you obtain `list` in the first place.

Comment: When I use `reverse_each` for `Task.all`, it's ok, now how can I use `reverse` for this: `list = Task.where(id: task.task_id, status: "onsolved")`. `reverse_each` don't work for this query.

Comment: There's no reason `list.reverse_each { |element| <do something> }` would not work; try it out in the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% list = Task.all.reverse %>
<% list.each do |element| %>
  <%= element.id %><br/>
<% end %>
```

[Array#reverse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reverse) is what you may be looking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `order`

```
  <% list = Task.order("id DESC") %>
  <% list.each do |element| %>
     <%= element.id %><br/>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: the only answer which looks like an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the lists before looping through the list. It should be something like this,

```
<% list = Task.all.reverse %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using reverse_each

list.reverse_each